# Creat Log-normal Random Variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution, probability-density

I have trouble with the probability density function (p.d.f) of a log-normal distribution. I really need your help. As defined by wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Probability_density_function

The probability density function of a log-normal distribution is:

[image: pdf of log-normal distribution]

My problem is, how to define x variable in MATLAB? Thanks for your help!

Comment: yeap, i have tried many time but it not successful. i really need hints from everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [Stats toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html), you can just use [`lognpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognpdf.html):

```
y = lognpdf(x,mu,sigma);
```

Though this is a very simple function - fully vectorized, it's effectively just:

> y = exp(-0.5*((log(x)-mu)./sigma).^2)./(x.*sqrt(2*pi).*sigma);

But you may want to check that `x > 0` and `sig > 0`. To create [this plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSome_log-normal_distributions.svg) on the Wikipedia article that you cited, you can do:

```
mu = 0;
sigma = [1;0.5;0.25];
x = 0:0.01:3;
y = lognpdf([x;x;x],mu,sigma(:,ones(1,length(x))));
figure; plot(x,y);
```

When your question asks about defining `x`, maybe you're actually looking for log-normally distributed [random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), i.e., you want to sample randomly from the log-normal PDF/distribution? In that case you can use [`lognrnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognrnd.html):

```
r = lognrnd(mu,sigma);
```

Comment: Thanks. maybe this is thing i am looking for. i will try again

Comment: i think that "x = 0:0.01:3;" should be replaced by x = 0:0.1:3; :)

Comment: @user2443165: It certainly can be replaced by that if you like. You'll just have a larger spacing between your `x` samples and end up with a blocky plot, just as with any discretizing any function.

Comment: Thanks my friend. i did it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, like you can do this in a one-liner,

```
fun = @(x,mu,sigma) (1./(x*sigma*sqrt(2*pi))).*exp( -(power((log(x)-mu),2))/(2*power(sigma,2)))
```

`x` is any value that satisfies `x > 0`, the pdf tells you via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)

> In probability theory, a probability density function (pdf), or
>   density of a continuous random variable, is a function that describes
>   the relative likelihood for this random variable to take on a given
>   value.

So any value `x` given to the log-normal pdf tells you tel relative likelihood that a random variable could be that value.

Consider this toy example:

```
mu = 1;
sigma = 10;
x = logspace(-2,0,10);
plot( x, fun(x,1,10) )
```

[image: log plot]

From this plot as `x` gets closer to zero, it's relative likelihood of actually taking on that value increases.  **DISCLAIMER** I just threw that function together, it needs to be checked for accuracy, the preceding was for illustration only.

Comment: I had not come across `logspace` before. Very nice use of that function!

Comment: Thanks. i will try by your hint, my friend!